# Setting key for each grid in grid view

Tags: flutter

How can I set a key for each grid in gridview? I thought that I can assign each key to each element of an array and after that I can set key to each widget in the grids but I couldn't insert keys into an array? Is there any way for that?

Comment: You can use ValueKey with item id

Comment: Actually I want to take offset of those grids without clicking. So, I guess I can't take with value key. Is there any way to assign global key?

Comment: maybe you can fetch offset inside initState with addPostFramecallback